# Gremlin to retrieve multiple properties based on its metaproperties

Tags: groovy, gremlin, janusgraph

I need to retrieve the vertex based on the metaproperties of several properties.

```
p.addV('v01').
    property(list, 'p01', 'p01value01', 'modified_by', 'user01', 'modified_date', '12/12/9999')
    property(list, 'p02', 'p02value01', 'modified_by', 'user01', 'modified_date', '12/12/2021')

p.addV('v01').
    property(list, 'p01', 'p01value02', 'modified_by', 'user01', 'modified_date', '12/12/2021')
    property(list, 'p02', 'p02value02', 'modified_by', 'user01', 'modified_date', '12/12/9999')
```

How do select the properties where the metaproperties (modified_by == '12/12/9999')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the meta properties as shown below. The `where` step filters out any vertex that does not have a property that matches. Youn can modify this query any way you need to if you want to return properties rather than vertices

```
g.V().where(properties().properties('modified_date').hasValue('12/12/9999'))
```

If you want the properties you can just move the where step.

```
g.V().properties().where(properties('modified_date').hasValue('12/12/9999')))
```

Comment: Hi Kelvin, is there a way to flat the results when I used g.V().properties().where(properties('modified_date').hasValue('12/12/9999')))

Comment: What do you mean by "flat the results"? Can you please give an example of what you need?

Comment: when using "where", the results will be 

==>vp[p01-> p01value01]
==>vp[p02-> p01value02]

How can i format it to be like this:
{props={p01=[p01value01], p02=[p01value02]}, id=16400, label=profile}

The reason is because i am using gremlin-python with flask and i want to parse it through jsonify

Comment: I found the answer in your blog! thanks!
.group().by(key).by(value)